# Fetch type out of range error, MSSQL, no control over calling code

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, cursors

I'm trying to modify the results of another applications stored procedure, so I  have no access to change the code that is reading the result set. (c#) but I can change the SP, Every time I modify the SP I get the error 'Fetch type out of range' . After searching stack overflow it appears that the software is calling this SP is using cursors, so my question is - 
Can I exclude some of the results below from being read by the client code and giving the error?

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Find_Door] @@somevar varchar(50)='' AS 

    --Normal part, return this
            SELECT a.[Name] FROM People AS a 

--Additional code, I don't want the cursor to be able to read.

          DECLARE ... 
          INSERT INTO Tables (col1,col2) VALUES ('val',getdate())       

---
```

Comment: I am not sure if I got it completely but cant you comment that code if you dont want it to be executed?

Comment: The application that calls this code still needs to see the results from the SELECT statement, I want to use the data for other purposes. at the time it is called.

Comment: I'm not really clear on what your issue is. Where is this cursor you're referring to?  What is the problem with the cursor?  Is it data being returned from the SP that is problematic, something in the SP, or what?

Comment: So I have an application (not mine) and a database.  I have full control over the database - but none over the application. 

The application calls the SP, but always returns an error after I edit it(the SP) - I'm trying to modify it to some additional SQLS

Comment: I found this page, but didn't help me that much